# Highest/lowest 3 consecutive columns in data set

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to find the highest sum of consecutive columns within a excel spreadsheet.

For example - say I wanted to find out the highest sum of any three consecutive columns from the following data: 1,2,3,12,8,4,1,1,12. The highest would be 24 (i.e. 12+8+4).

I am not looking for the highest three columns in general (which would be 12,8,12) but rather the highest three consecutive columns.

I would also like the formula to either highlight the columns included in the maximum, or output the column name, so that I can easily identify which cells have the highest consecutive value.

For more context, we are trying to show the most profitable 12 and 36 months within a series of data. The data is monthly (i.e. August 2019 - 10%, June 2019 - 5% e.t.c) The only constraint is the month.

Comment: This is very vague, you need some sort of rule on how these values can be consecutive. Is it through any mathematical operator like `+` or `-` or `*`? Include your own effort too.

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks for your answer. Apologies, I've never used stackoverflow before so not sure of how things work around here! The data is monthly, therefore the consecutive rule would be consecutive months. For more context, we are trying to show the most profitable 12 and 36 months within a series of data. The only constraint is the month. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @HSTech, but unfortunateley this isn't much clearer (at least to me). Please have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Also taking the site's [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution via a User Defined function which returns the column number of the first column of the n consecutive columns giving the highest sum.

you can then reuse this info to compute the sum and set up a MFC to highlight the corresponding columns

UDF : (to insert in a new module)

```
    Function maxsumcons(r, n&) As Long
' return the index of the first column in range r of the  n consecutive columns giving the max sum

    Dim maxi&, maxs, s, i&, j&
    For i = 1 To r.Count - n + 1
        s = 0
        For j = i To i + n - 1
            s = s + r(1, j).Value
        Next j
        If s > maxs Then maxs = s: maxi = i
    Next i
    maxsumcons = maxi

End Function
```

now suppose your data are in A2:I2
you can use the following formula (let us say in K2) =maxsumcons(A2:I2,3) to get the first column of the highest sum and reuse this info to compute this sum with a formula like this one : =sum(offset(A1,1,K2-1,1,3))

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use helper rows, you can use the following formulas. I assume your data is in B1:B9 and the number of consecutive values you want to examine in D1 as shown in this picture:

[image]

**Step 1** Create the range of consecutive values:

```
=MMULT(
  --(ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9)))*--(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9))<ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))+3),
  B1:B9),
```

**Step 2** Find the index of the maximum's first element (if there are multiple maximums, return the first):

```
=MATCH(
  MAX(
    MMULT(
      --(ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9)))*--(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9))<ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))+3),
      B1:B9)),
  MMULT(
    --(ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9)))*--(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9))<ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))+3),
    B1:B9),
  0)
```

**Step 3** Get the values in the maximum:

```
=OFFSET(
  B1:B9,
  MATCH(
    MAX(
      MMULT(
        --(ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9)))*--(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9))<ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))+3),
        B1:B9)),
    MMULT(
      --(ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9)))*--(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9))<ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))+3),
      B1:B9),
    0)-1,
  0,
  D1,
  1)
```

**Step 4** Calculate the sum:

```
=SUM(
  OFFSET(
    B1:B9,
    MATCH(
      MAX(
        MMULT(
          --(ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9)))*--(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9))<ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))+3),
          B1:B9)),
      MMULT(
        --(ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9)))*--(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B9))<ROW(OFFSET(B1:B9,0,0,ROWS(B1:B9)-D1+1,1))+3),
        B1:B9),
      0)-1,
    0,
    D1,
    1)
  )
```

Note: It is important to enter these formulas as array formulas (You have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter only, and you will see the formula in curly braces).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way...

[image]

For the highest amount, enter the following formula in K2, and confirm with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=MAX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A2:I2,,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(A2:I2)-3+1))-1,,3)))
```

For the corresponding 3 consecutive months, select cells L2:N2, enter the following formula, and confirm with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(A1:I1,MATCH(K2,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A2:I2,,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(A2:I2)-3+1))-1,,3)),0)),,,,3)
```